# Perl - decide whether to run script based on third octet of IP address

Tags: perl, ip

Here are 3 sample ip addresses:

> 192.168.1.2
>
> 192.168.2.2
>
> 192.168.3.2

I want this script to run ONLY if the third octate of the ip address is 3. If the third octate of the client's ip address is not 3 than I would like the script to abort.

Comment: here are three examples of ip addresses that will be allowed to run the script: 192.168.3.2, 192.168.3.3, and 192.168.3.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($addr =~ /^\d+\.\d+\.3\.\d+$/) {

  # do your stuff

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're talking about a Perl CGI script. If so, from http://www.perlfect.com/articles/cgi_env.shtml:

> REMOTE_ADDR
>
> The IP address from which the client is issuing the request.
>
> This can be useful either for logging accesses to the script (for
>   example a voting script might want to
>   log voters in a file by their IP in
>   order to prevent them from voting more
>   than once) or to block/behave
>   differently for particular IP
>   adresses. (this might be a requirement
>   in a script that has to be restricted
>   to your local network, and maybe
>   perform different tasks for each known
>   host)

So you should be able to parse %ENV{'REMOTE_ADDR'} and adjust your execution accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
use NetAddr::IP;
if (my $addr = NetAddr::IP->new($src) and $addr->within(NetAddr::IP->new('192.168.3.0/24')) {
     ....
}
```

This will of course then be trivial to change to IPv6 support, expand the subnet of allowed host, check against multiple subnets, etc.